# Failed to connect to Mir on Travis Server

Tags: ubuntu, travis-ci, tycho

I have a Maven / Tycho build running on Travis CI, and I'm getting the following exception when running the tests:

```
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

I was able to find a couple of forum entries explaining that this error means the Travis server is headless and evidently Eclipse needs a display to run. There were even some ideas on how to fix this issue, but none on how to achieve this using Travis and its *.travis.yml* config file.

---

[Gnome Issue #207](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/207) states you need to do `sudo apt-get install xauth xvfb`, so I tried it with:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - xauth
      - xvfb
```

The server logs:

> xauth is already the newest version (1:1.0.9-1ubuntu2).
>
> xvfb is already the newest version (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8).

...and still fails.

---

[Eclipse Docker Issue#1](https://github.com/DrSnowbird/eclipse-docker/issues/1) states `export DISPLAY=:0.0` might help, so I tried:

```
before_install:
  - export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Which gets executed, but the exception still gets thrown.

---

Clearly I've no idea what I'm doing - I'm not good with Linux so I have no idea how to fix any of this, and I'm not deeply familiar with Travis either, so that's a problem as well.

Is there any way to get a Tycho build with UI to run on a Travis server? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the relevant portion of the [Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-a-GUI):

*The following will start xvfb and set the right values for the DISPLAY environment variable:*

```
dist: xenial
services:
  - xvfb
```